# Does Magento 1.x follow any coding convention?

Tags: magento-1, code-analysis

I didn't find any official resource saying that Magento 1.x follow a coding convention. Do you know which coding convention Magento 1.x follows?

Thanks

Comment: As Magento is built on Zend it will follow a lot of their coding conventions but as to how strict they do this I'm not too sure

Comment: Not an answer, but this was recently released by the Magento ECG team to check standards: https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard